# Requests.history Not printing python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm a noob to python programming. I have a simple problem. Im using python3, in pyCharm 2017.2.1, I want to print out all request redirects. From what I have googled I seem to be doing it right. I get no errors and a response 200. What am I missing?

```
import requests
url='http://httpbin.org/html'
payload= {'url':'http://bing.com'}

req = requests.get(url, params=payload)
#print(req.text)
print("Response code: " + str(req.status_code))

if req.history:
    print ("Request was redirected")
    for resp in req.history:
        print (resp.status_code, resp.url)
        print ( "Final destination:")
        print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
    else:
        print("Request was not redirected")


for x in req.history:
    print(str(x.status_code) + ' : ' + x.url)
```

output:

```
Response code: 200

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use this url: `http://httpbin.org/redirect-to`, 
the url you're using will not redirect your request. Also the else block is not executed because it applies to the for loop.

```
import requests

url='http://httpbin.org/redirect-to'
payload= {'url':'http://bing.com'}
req = requests.get(url, params=payload)

print("Response code: " + str(req.status_code))
if req.history:
    print ("Request was redirected")
    for resp in req.history:
        print("Final destination:")
        print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
else:
    print("Request was not redirected")

for x in req.history:
    print(str(x.status_code) + ' : ' + x.url)
```

Note that you can disable redirects if you set the `allow_redirects` parameter to `False`

Comment: Thanks for the Help. it worked!  Side-note: the 'else' statement did execute, just not the way I intended lol. I brought it out so it is with the 'if req.history:'